# Lost keys and have no obd port, what should I do?

Tags: security, obd

Car is a civic vti 1999.  Lost the keys and auto locksmith is saying he needs the obd port otherwise he can't reprogram it.

I cannot find  it on the car and a friend tells me these hondas do not have these ports. Note that mine is the uk version I think the US version did come with obd port.

What should I do without the obd port in sight?

Comment: This guy *says* he's a locksmith but he doesn't know how to find the answer himself? Best find a *real* locksmith, IMO - one who has heard about Google, for example.

Comment: If you have lost the keys and don't have a spare set... Then go to a dealer and they can supply keys using the numbers which might be in the owners handbook or possibly on the barrel. If not, then the car gets a new set of locks and keys...

Comment: If your key has a security chip and you lose all copies of that key/chip you will probably need to reflash your ECU, I had to for a Lexus. OBD port may provide ECU access, didn't look into it. For mine, I removed the ECU and sent it out to a qualified locksmith. This would also be an option for you.

Comment: What engine do you have?

Comment: I meant size, liters.

Comment: @Moab. It's a 1.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the UK I obd was only fully compliant by car manufacturers for petrol cars from 2001 and 2004 for diesel cars, so many older cars did not come with an obd port. Your particular car of that year does not have an obd port however it does have a different type of port which you can use to program in the new key.
Some auto locksmiths only work on newer cars and are not experienced with the older so find a autolocksmith who has experience with older cars.  If they only work on obd cars, they are not the right person to go to.